# Responsive Native Express Ads Units

Tags: android, admob

I want to make my Native Express Ads Units responsive so that it covers the width of the screen.Right now, I am using fixed size Unit.

Please suggest how can I make this Ad Unit responsive.

***Layout.xml***

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6667404740993831/9531692095"
        ads:adSize=400x400">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
```

Comment: tried this? https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize.html#FULL_WIDTH

Comment: can you please let me know how can I implement this?

Comment: try changing adSize to ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"